Woocommerce ajax remove button won't remove item from cart but returns { success: false }
In the design for the shop I'm building, the add to cart button changes to a remove from cart button on the woocommerce/content-product.php file of the woocommerce theme overrides to allow users to correct the items that were added to the card.
Only when the remove button is clicked, the user gets send to the homepage and the item is still in the cart. If I inspect the javascript, the ajax call does return success but the value is 'false' and I can't really find out what's causing that.
In the woocommerce/content-product.php I added a remove button, with all the values available at that time
<a href="" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" 
aria-label="Remove <?php echo($product->get_name() ); ?> from cart" 
data-product_id="<?php echo($product->get_id() ); ?>" 
data-cart_item_key="" data-product_sku="<?php echo($product->get_sku()); ?>" 
id="remove-<?php echo($product->get_id() ); ?>">Remove from enquiry</a>

When an item gets added to the cart, I update the data on the remove button with what gets returned and add an event handler for when someone clicks the button.
It gets updated with the hash and the url gets updated with the right value. But on clicking it gives the status { success: false } and nothing that hints on where the problem lies.
The code seems nearly the same as Woocoommerce does it in there add-to-cart.js
jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function(event, fragments, cart_hash, $button) {
    // Retrieve information about the product from the button's data attributes
    var productId = $button.data('product_id');

    var remove_button = document.getElementById('remove-' + productId);
    remove_button.setAttribute('data-cart_item_key', cart_hash);
    remove_button.setAttribute('href', '?remove_item=' + cart_hash);

    remove_button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var updated_hash = event.target.getAttribute('data-cart_item_key');
        // Send AJAX request to remove the item from the cart
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "remove_from_cart"),
            data: {
                //action: 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item',
                cart_item_key: updated_hash
            },
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                // Handle success response (optional)
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle error response (optional)
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});


Edit: So I managed to solve it. The message that got returned threw me off and send me looking in the wrong direction. See the comment below for the details about the message.
Here's the code that works:
jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function(event, fragments, cart_hash, $button) {
    // Retrieve information about the product from the button's data attributes
    var productId = $button.data('product_id');
    // fragments returns the mini cart, the hash isn't passed separately anymore
    var $fragments = jQuery(Object.values(fragments)[0]);

    var remove_button = document.getElementById('remove-' + productId);
    // Get the remove buttons for all the products returned, and find the one matching the one I want
    var $remove_buttons = $fragments.find('.remove_from_cart_button');
    for (var btn of $remove_buttons) {
        if ( productId == jQuery(btn).data('product_id') ) {
            // If this is the right product, set the values on the button. The rest is as it was
            remove_button.setAttribute('data-cart_item_key', jQuery(btn).data('cart_item_key') );
            remove_button.setAttribute('data-product_sku', jQuery(btn).data('product_sku') );
        }
    }

    remove_button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var updated_hash = event.target.getAttribute('data-cart_item_key');
        // Send AJAX request to remove the item from the cart
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "remove_from_cart"),
            data: {
                cart_item_key: updated_hash,
            },
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                // Handle success response (optional)
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle error response (optional)
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});


You would need to debug. For example console.log the wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "remove_from_cart"), or something

Hi @mplungjan , thanks for the reply.
I assumed it would be correct as Woocommerce uses it like this too, but it's worth a shot.
If I console.log this:
console.log(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "remove_from_cart"));
I get this as a result:
/?wc-ajax=remove_from_cart
That seems fine to me? Also it gives a 200 in the server logs, so I get the feeling the problem is in the data I pass or something.

So perhaps not that. I would change such code to const url = new URL(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url); and then later use url.searchParams.set('wc','remove_from_cart'); jQuery.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: url.toString()... but I am suspicious of your commenting out of data: { action: 

Hi, I managed to find the solution but I had to debug the source of Woocommerce to find it.
It seems the remove_from_cart method of WC_Cart calls wp_send_json_error() if the hash isn't matching and that function annoyingly sends success: false if nothing is passed along.
So this made me think the call was actually good, while it wasn't. I was mixing up the hash of the cart with the hash of an actual product.

The solution was that I was thrown off by an unclear error, which was posing as a success message. I was using the cart hash instead of the product hash.
The fixed code is in the post, and also below here. I hope this is the right way to do it?
jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function(event, fragments, cart_hash, $button) {
    // Retrieve information about the product from the button's data attributes
    var productId = $button.data('product_id');
    // fragments returns the mini cart, the hash isn't passed separately anymore
    var $fragments = jQuery(Object.values(fragments)[0]);

    var remove_button = document.getElementById('remove-' + productId);
    // Get the remove buttons for all the products returned, and find the one matching the one I want
    var $remove_buttons = $fragments.find('.remove_from_cart_button');
    for (var btn of $remove_buttons) {
        if ( productId == jQuery(btn).data('product_id') ) {
            // If this is the right product, set the values on the button. The rest is as it was
            remove_button.setAttribute('data-cart_item_key', jQuery(btn).data('cart_item_key') );
            remove_button.setAttribute('data-product_sku', jQuery(btn).data('product_sku') );
        }
    }

    remove_button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var updated_hash = event.target.getAttribute('data-cart_item_key');
        // Send AJAX request to remove the item from the cart
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%", "remove_from_cart"),
            data: {
                cart_item_key: updated_hash,
            },
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                // Handle success response (optional)
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle error response (optional)
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});


Sure, if it is a problem that others might have too
